# Relative Layout alternative for weighted Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to do a 1:3:6 weight adjustment using relative layout?

I have a relative layout and I need to place 3 UI components  inside it using the ratio 1:3:6. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a linear layout (vertical or horizontal depending on your needs) inside this `RelativeLayout`, deciding its position as usual. And the inside the `LinearLayout` assign weights to the three elements to the ratio you want.

They will fill the `LinearLayout` while giving you the ability of placing it relatively in your layout.

Comment: then that relative layout is possible useless rite!!...With the linear layout itself I could do that..Actually I need to lace this realtiveLayout as a weighted somponent of anothe alyout...Thats why man...its showing the bad performance warning :)

Comment: Depending on your particular layout, you may or may not be able to do without a `RelativeLayout`, I'm unaware of the particulars of your design, but **useless** is a harsh word

Comment: sorry dear..I didnt mean it actually.. sorry :)

Comment: google suggests that whenever possible , prefer the relativeLayout over other LinearLayout. the reason is performance - it's relatively easy for the CPU to handle such layouts.

Answer (score 0):

relativeLayout is used for putting views in relation to each other (this on the right of that , this on the top of that,...) . it has nothing to do with sizes.
if you want to have weights , use LinearLayout and weights for each of the children as needed.

Comment: I cant use linear layout here dear...because Im using this as a weighted component inside another linearlayoyt..so its showing bad performance warning...hence I thought of using relative layout here instead of using linear layout with weights :) :)

Comment: the bad performance occurs only during layouts phase . if you don't change the layout much ,it's ok , especially if all you have is simply 3 views. if you don't change it at all , you get a slightly slower initialization at the beginning of the activity.

Comment: okk thanks a lot fo ur reply:)

Comment: if you want the best performance , you can use opengl , but that would be like inventing the wheel .

Comment: anyway, kindly tick this answer as the one that answers your question .

Comment: did you tick it? i can't see the "V" mark for some reason.

Comment: sorry ...earlier..my click didnt wrk...is it okk now?

Comment: yes thanks. for more tips , you can check the google io videos , for example : http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html#android-track

Comment: thanks..definitely i will watch those videos :)

Comment: you didn't tick this answer. :(